# History of "Show that $44\dots 88 \dots 9$ is a perfect square"

Tags: reference-request, math-history

The problem

> Show that the sequence, $49, 4489, 444889, \dots$, gotten by inserting
>   the digits $48$ in the middle of the
>   previous number (all in base $10$), consists only of 
>   perfect squares.

has become a classic. For some reason, I got curious as to who actually discovered this.

After doing some research, seems like this problem was used in the Stanford University Competitive Exam in Mathematics for high school seniors, in the year 1964. One pdf which has this is here: http://www.computing-wisdom.com/jstor/stanford-exam.pdf. It appears as problem 64.2.

The pdf also mentions that there is a booklet which gives references to previous appearances of the problems from the above exam, but that seemed to be a dead-end regarding this particular problem.

> Does anyone know who originally
>   discovered this little gem? More
>   interestingly, is it known *how* this
>   was discovered?

**Update 1**

On some more research I found this book from 1903: [Algebra Part II](http://books.google.com/books?id=3D04AAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover) by E.M. Langley and S.R.N. Bradly which has this as an exercise on [page 180](http://books.google.com/books?id=3D04AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA180). The question seems to have been phrased in such a way as to claim ownership and also tells *how* it was discovered. I guess we just need confirmation now.

**Update 2**

More digging reveals this German book by Dr. Hermann Schubert, [Mathematische Mussestunden](http://books.google.com/books?id=seEGAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q&f=false), which has this on [page 24](http://books.google.com/books?id=seEGAAAAYAAJ&dq=shubert%20mathematische%2067%20667&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false). The book was published in 1900, but the preface seems to be dated earlier. If someone can read German, perhaps maybe they can read and see what the book claims about the origins of this problem. The book seems to have a list of references at the beginning.

Comment: Not sure of the tags, please feel free to change/add.

Comment: Have you tried Dickson?

Comment: @Matthew: I haven't even heard of Dickson! Who/What is it?

Comment: @Moron: Presumably, Matthew asks you to refer the historical text written on Mathematics in 3 volumes.

Comment: According to the book: Index to mathematical Problems, by Stanley Rabinowitz, Mark Bowron, this problem originates in the Ontario Secondary School Mathematics Bulletin from 1975 (see here: http://books.google.com/books?id=KX6D6hefyA0C&lpg=PA187&dq=%2249%2C%204489%22&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q=%2249,%204489%22&f=false) -- but that is clearly wrong in light of the link to the Stanford exam that you have put up there. I would guess that this problem is much older.

Comment: @Chandru: I see, Thanks. I will check that.

Comment: Yes, Dickson's History of the Theory of Numbers, volume 1, Chapter XX ("Properties of the Digits of Numbers") is a place to look.  I just glanced through it, though, and didn't find specifically your phenomenon, but there is enough there to convince me that this was well known prior to 1900, so I think you'll have to dig to find the earliest source. Dickson mentions many square related digit results, and also mentions "similar problems" and "collections of problems".

Comment: @Matt: I found a book from 1903 that has this, and which might be the source (see update to question). But, I agree with you and am guessing this has got to be older.

Comment: @Moron: Nice find.  I bet this result is no more than a year younger than the decimal system, though a solid proof might be a bit younger than that.

Comment: I think my rudimentary German is enough for me to claim that the Schubert book makes no claims as to the origin of the problem, at least not in the vicinity of the problem itself.  This is the kind of phenomenon that has been discovered over and over again since the invention of the decimal system, and I'm sure numerous folks have come up with myriad (most virtually identical) independent proofs.  As a result, I expect most authors would not give a reference for it in their works.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah, I agree. I was just wondering if that book made any references. I found this from the references of a 1912 book, so some do give references. But, I guess you are right, this problem is likely to be very old and finding the oldest reference is probably the best we can do.

Comment: @Moron: It is fun to try to find the earliest reference for things.  Did you get a chance to look through Dickson?  It's one of my favorite books for perusing.

Comment: @Matt: Yes it is :-) I am planning to check the libraries around here for a copy of Dickson. I can't seem to find an online copy.

Comment: Your link to the "Mussestunden" does not work for me. I wanted to check it (as I can read german, it is my native language), but Google does not show the contents. Could this be dependent on my location (in Germany, here)?

Comment: @Paŭlo: Yes, I believe google books is location dependent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

UPDATE:

This fact appeared as a problem in the October 1, 1889 issue of the [Journal de Mathématiques Elémentaires](http://books.google.fr/books?id=QNoLAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA160&ots=HRjtdDz8Vo&dq=%2249%204489%20444889%22&pg=PA160#v=onepage&q=%2249%204489%20444889%22&f=false), page 160. The problem is attributed to F. Briganti of the Ecole de industrielle de Fermo.

---

I don't yet have the rep to leave a comment so I'll leave this as an answer...

This fact appears in a note of M. C.-A. Laisant in 1892. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=bC7PAAAAMAAJ&dq=%2249%204489%20444889%22&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q=%2249%204489%20444889%22&f=false), page 77. He remarks that this "cette remarque, paraît-il, a été faite depuis longtemps" (this remark, it seems, was made a long time ago). No references are given. Later in the same volume, in the minutes of the February 27, 1892 meeting of the Société Philomathique de Paris, this fact is referred to as a "fait connu" - a known fact - so perhaps this was already known at the time.

So it seems that you will have to dig much farther back to find the original source.

(The page numbers in this Google Books version don't seem to work, but just search for 4489 and you should find the two references to this fact.)

Comment: @Aryabhata - I added a new source from 1889. My guess is that you won't find anything much older on the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will wait a few more days (bounty period) and accept this as the answer (and the bounty answer). (Just in case F.Briganti got it from elsewhere!)