# Does this pattern continue $\lfloor\sqrt{44}\rfloor=6, \lfloor\sqrt{4444}\rfloor=66,\dots$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

By observing the following I have a feeling that the pattern continues.

$$\lfloor \sqrt{44} \rfloor=6$$
$$\lfloor \sqrt{4444} \rfloor=66$$
$$\lfloor \sqrt{444444} \rfloor=666$$
$$\lfloor \sqrt{44444444} \rfloor=6666$$

But I'm unable to prove it. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by showing that the sequence $a_n=\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n44\cdot 100^i}}{\sum_{i=0}^n 6\cdot 10^i}$ converges to $1$. This might give you a clue where the answer comes from.

Comment: Nice observation (+1)

Comment: Well, $4=2^2$, so your pattern is the same as, $$\begin{align}\lfloor\sqrt{11}\rfloor&=6\div 2 = 3 \\ \lfloor\sqrt{1111}\rfloor&=33 \\ \lfloor\sqrt{111111}\rfloor&=333 \\ &\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: This is a (very elegant!) variation of a well known puzzle: show that the pattern$$7^2=49\ ,\quad 67^2=4489\ ,\quad 667^2=444889\ ,\quad 6667^2=44448889$$continues indefinitely, proved for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529597/prove-that-in-a-sequence-of-numbers-49-4489-444889-44448889-ldots).

Comment: Actually with decimals, you have $\sqrt{0.444444444444...}=0.66666666666...$.

Answer (score 27):

Hint :

We have $$\left(\frac{6\cdot (10^n-1)}{9}\right)^2=\frac{4\cdot (10^{2n}-1)}{9}-\frac{8\cdot (10^n-1)}{9}$$

Try to find out why this proves that the pattern continues forever.

Comment: I have no idea how to prove it. Would you please do it for me?

Comment: @user571036 The equation has the form $a^2=b-c$. It is easy to see that $c<2a$. Now , we have $a^2=b-c<b$ , hence $a<\sqrt{b}$ and $(a+1)^2=a^2+2a+1=b-c+2a+1=b+1+2a-c>b+1>b$, hence $a+1>\sqrt{b}$. Hence, $\lfloor \sqrt{b} \rfloor=a$

Comment: Thanks. Which grade is this taught?

Comment: @user571036 I am not sure whether such things are taught at all.

Comment: Then how did you get to know?

Comment: To find $\lfloor \sqrt{b} \rfloor$, we have to find the (unique) integer $a$ with $a\le \sqrt{b}<a+1$ that is simply the deifinition. Here the left inequality is also strict. The main problem was to establish the equation. I tried some cases and guessed it.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. You were so nice throughout the conversation.

Comment: How do you learn to solve such things?  The solution comes from finding patterns in the problem.  Most people just learn to find such patterns over the years without explicit training in methods of solving.  There's nothing in the equation beyond say early high school.  There are techniques though if you want to study them.  For example, the book "How to Solve It", by renowned mathematician G. Polya but aimed for general audiences, is a good source.

Answer (score 7):

This can be proved a bit more simple.

The general term can be written as $4 \frac{10^{2n} - 1}{9}$. Taking square root will give you $\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{10^{2n} - 1}$. As $\frac{2}{3} \approx 0.66666666666$ and $\sqrt{10^{2n} - 1} \approx \sqrt{10^{2n}} = 10^n$, this explains why the result is $6;66;666;...$ etc. To prove rigorously, observe that: $66...66 = \frac{2}{3} 10^n - \frac{2}{3} < \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{10^{2n} - 1} < \frac{2}{3} 10^n = 66...66.67$.

Comment: I think the rigorous part is not rigorous enough. The two bounds you give are not sufficient in explaining why flooring the value gives a $6$ as the last digit.

Comment: @M.Winter if you have a number in the interval $[665.67 ; 666.67]$, then its floor value must be $666$, isn't it?

Comment: Flooring means rounding to the smaller integer, so flooring 665.67 gives 665.

Comment: I'm not rounding both sides of the inequality. I rounded only the middle term.

Comment: and what if the middle term turns out to be 665.68 for example?

Comment: @SiXUlm Yes, of course, but the middle term can be (if we only know about these bounds) 665.99. and if you floor this, you get 665. You need to show that the middle term is $\ge 666$.

Comment: nice squeeze there

Comment: @SiXUlm sorry, consider 665.68. I made a typo.

Comment: @M.Winter I see, you are correct. I edited the answer.

Comment: @SiXUlm Much better. Thanks for editing. One still has to reason why $10^n-1<\sqrt{10^{2n}-1}$, but this is quite easy I assume you leave that to the reader.

Comment: @M.Winter yes, it is just basic manipulation, so I leave the detail to the readers. Thanks again for pointing out the error in my argument.

Answer (score 4):

As a somewhat inferior alternative to Peter's algebraic approach,
you could work out a square root in long-division style as shown here:

\begin{array}{r}
                    6 \; \phantom{0}6 \;\phantom{0}6 \;\phantom{0}6 \\[-3pt]
                \sqrt{44 \; 44 \; 44 \; 44} \\[-3pt]
            \underline{36}\;   \phantom{66 \; 00 \; 00} \\[-3pt]
12\underline6|\phantom{0}8 \; 44 \phantom{\; 00 \; 00}\\[-3pt]
              \underline{7 \; 56} \phantom{\; 00 \; 00}\\[-3pt]
       132\underline{6} |\phantom{0} \; 88 \; 44 \phantom{\; 00}\\[-3pt]
                   \underline{79 \; 56} \phantom{\; 00}\\[-3pt]
      1332\underline{6} | \phantom{0}8 \; 88 \;44\\[-3pt]
                   \underline{7 \; 99 \; 56}
\end{array}

From here you may be able to extrapolate some provable patterns that 
occur as you append more pairs of $4$s to the digits under the square root sign.