# What is the sum of the digits of the square root of this number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently working on an Olympiad math problem, and I am struggling to find a solution. I would greatly appreciate your help in solving this problem. I was unable to solve the problem because I don't know the exact rules for solving the problem.
***Problem Source:*** Bangladesh Math Olympiad

*A small help will be enough for me to proceed.*

> Here is a number (444...888...9) that has the 2018
> digits of 4, followed by 2017 digits of 8
> and one digit of 9. Find the sum of the
> digits of the square root of this number.

Comment: [Hint](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1892170p12914828)

Comment: I suggest starting with numbers smaller than $2018$ to get the pattern (it's pretty evident once you work some examples).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529597/prove-that-in-a-sequence-of-numbers-49-4489-444889-44448889-ldots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by noting the pattern
$$49=7^2
\\4489=67^2
\\444889=667^2$$

Now, try to prove using induction (or otherwise) that
$$\underbrace{4\dots 4}_{n\text{ times}}\;\underbrace{8\dots 8}_{n-1\text{ times}}\;9=\left(\underbrace{6\dots 6}_{n-1\text{ times}}\;7\right)^2$$
Once you do that, the rest is easy.

Comment: Brilliant you are !!!