# Prove all numbers in a sequence are perfect squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions

Let sequence $49,4489,444889,...$ is formed when in between digits $4$ and $9$ is the number $48$. For any number larger than $444889$ continue to put $48$.

Example: $49,4489,444889,44448889,...$
Prove that all numbers in the sequence are perfect squares.

I think of finding generating function of the sequence and then the closed form of a sequence.

How to evaluate generation function (in $\sum\limits$ notation)?

Comment: Related: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529597/prove-that-in-a-sequence-of-numbers-49-4489-444889-44448889), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16946/history-of-show-that-44-dots-88-dots-9-is-a-perfect-square).

Comment: Perhaps a clearer way of putting it is $n$ fours followed by $n - 1$ 8s and followed by 9.  Or more formally $a_n = $9 + \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1}8*10^i + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}4*10^{n+1}$.  Do I have that right?

Answer (score 4):

A number $444\ldots 4$ consisting of $n$ fours is equal to $(10^n-1)\cdot\frac{4}{9}$, see why for yourself.

Then the number consisting of $n/2$ fours, then $n/2-1$ eights and then a nine is equal to:

$$\frac{4}{9}(10^n-1)+\frac{4}{9}(10^{n/2}-1)+1=\frac{4}{9}(10^n+10^{n/2}+\frac{1}{4})$$

which you can easily see to be equal to:

$$(\ \frac{2}{3}(10^{n/2}+\frac{1}{2})\ )^2$$

which is the square of:

$$\frac{1}{3}(1+2\cdot10^{n/2}) $$

The thing in the parenthesis is most certainly divisible by $3$, so the number we started off with was a perfect square.

Comment: If n = 1 then $49 = \frac 1 3 (1 + 2*10^{n/2}) = \frac 1 3(1 + 2*10^0) = 1$??????

Comment: I think you meant $\frac 4 9(10^{n/2 + 1} - 1)*10{n/2} + \frac 8 9(10^{n/2} - 1) + 9$.

Comment: Read the answer carefully again. $n/2$ is implied to be a whole number, when I say "number consisting of $n/2$ fours...". I chose $n$ to be the total length of the number in question.